# Como capturar una petición AJAX - JQuery con PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Intento enviar una petición AJAX a una página PHP. La respuesta es "sucess" pero no la capturo correctamente en el archivo PHP, he intentado con varios formatos, ya que me interesa la respuesta y no lo que envío, solo capturar la petición y contestarla, y no soy capaz de capturarla correctamente. Mi código es el siguiente:

Archivo PHP

```
<?php
include 'conn_esp.php';
$pais ='a';
 $conn = connection();

 if(isset($_POST['pidiendoluz'])){

    $pais = 'guay';
    $pais = $_POST['pidiendoluz'];
    echo '<br>'.$pais ;
}
echo '<br>'.$pais ;
?>
```

---

Archivo JS:

$(document).ready(function () {
var pidiendoluz = "urug";

```
  $("#pidiendoluz").click(function () {
    var jsxhr = $.ajax({
      url: "RecibiendoPeticion.php",
      type: "POST",
      //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      //contentType:'text/plain',
      data: pidiendoluz,
      beforeSend: function () {
        alert(pidiendoluz);
      },
      success: function () {
        alert("sucess");
      },
    });

    jsxhr.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        alert("Not connect: Verify Network.");
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        alert("Requested page not found [404]");
      } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        alert("Internal Server Error [500].");
      } else if (textStatus === "parsererror") {
        alert("Requested JSON parse failed.");
      } else if (textStatus === "timeout") {
        alert("Time out error.");
      } else if (textStatus === "abort") {
        alert("Ajax request aborted.");
      } else {
        alert("Uncaught Error: " + jqXHR.responseText);
      }
    });
  }); // end #pidiendoluz

  
}); //end doc.ready
```

Comment: que te interesa de la respuesta??? el status o el contenido de la respuesta??

Comment: Hola Francisco. Me interesa que php capture la petición, por lo que leo en jquery, podría capturar clave : valor, pero la variable global S_POST no captura nada parece, aunque la respuesta es sucess, o sea enviada correctamente la petición al servidor

Comment: la variable en php es $_POST con símbolo de dolare y no se trata de pasar una variable se trata de pasar un set de datos de formulario: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Creo que la parte del código php: `$pais="guai";` Esta de mas.

Answer (score 2):

Como te decía en los comentario el método adecuando para enviar datos por `ajax` es creando un `set` de datos de formulario, esto se consigue con:

```
var formData = new FormData(); // Currently empty
formData.append('pidiendoluz', 'urug'); //add a key value element
```

entonces en tu `ajax` envías el objeto `formData`:

```
 var jsxhr = $.ajax({
      url: "RecibiendoPeticion.php",
      type: "POST",
      //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      //contentType:'text/plain',
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      },
    });
```

Documentación asociada:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Otro Ejemplo:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/476680/46896

como acceder a la informacion en php, Si enviaste el objeto de arriba quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
echo $_POST['pidiendoluz'];

#output:
urug
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero el objeto FormData me da error en JQuery. Lo he intentado mandar como clave :valor en unavariable , el objeto se crea y me contesta done, como que lo ha enviado, pero mi código php no captura nada. Seguiré intentándolo

Comment: y que contiene $_POST puedes imprimir con var_dump y agregarlo a tus comentarios o pregunta???

Comment: Lo he conseguido, pero lo he vuelto a estropear, cosas del directo, muchas gracias por tu apoyo. El FormData () no me  lo acepta jQuery 3.6 !?, Pero con un new http request, o sea sin jQuery si lo conseguí. El fallo estaba en que intentaba capturar en PHP el nombre del formulario en vez de la variable contenida en él. Ahora lo volví a estropear pero ya lo tengo, supongo. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: @Diegol ok entonces agrega o marca la respuesta que mas se acerca a tu solución.

Comment: @Diegol que raro new FormData es un objeto de JavaScript, no depende de la version de JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que acceder a los `datos` que retorna la llamada:

```
var jsxhr = $.ajax({
      url: "RecibiendoPeticion.php",
      type: "POST",
      //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      //contentType:'text/plain',
      data: pidiendoluz,
      beforeSend: function () {
        alert(pidiendoluz);
      },
      success: function (data) {
        // `data` son los resultados de la llamada
        alert(data);
        alert("sucess");
      },
    });
```