# Procesar formulario con jquery y php

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un formulario y para procesarlo hago lo siguiente:

```
formdatax = {
    tipo_reg: "producto",
    producto: $("#producto").val(),
    new_categoria: new_categoria,
    categoria: categoria,
    new_marca: new_marca,
    marca: marca,
    ubicacion: $("#ubicacion").val(),
    precio_costo : $("#precio_costo").val(),
    precio_minimo : $("#precio_minimo").val(),
    precio_mayor: $("#precio_mayor").val(),
    precio_venta: $("#precio_venta").val(),
    precio_consumidor: $("#precio_consumidor").val(),
    codigo_barras: $("#codigo_barras").val(),
    codigo_producto: $("#codigo_producto").val(),
    codigo_interno: $("#codigo_interno").val()
};
```

Eso es la data y ahora para procesarlo uso esto:

```
$.post("procesos/registrar.php",formdatax).done(function(respp){
 alert(respp);
 //location.reload();
});
```

Hasta allí todo bien, el problema surge en que quiero subir una imagen y anexarlo al post.

Mi input:

```
<input id="foto_producto" type="file" name="fotoproducto"/>
```

Intenté con esto:

```
var formData = new FormData();
var files = $('#foto_producto')[0].files[0];
formData.append('file',files);
```

Y a mi post le envío así:

```
$.post("procesos/registrar.php",formdatax+formData).done(function(respp){
     alert(respp);
     //location.reload();
    });
```

Pero el php no detecta la imagen.

Comment: Si identificas el formulario y lo pasas en parámetro al constructor de FormData éste lo serializa directamente, no tienes que meterle ningún dato a mano, esa es precisamente una de las ventajas de usar FormData, eso incluye también a los inputs de tipo file.

Comment: el problema es que yo valido en el front algunos campos y de acuerdo a ello muestro otros campos

Comment: No entiendo qué quieres decir con eso, ¿qué algunos de los datos que guardas en `formdatax` no están en el formulario  y/o que el formulario tiene datos que no te interesan? Puedes serializar el formulario y si hay datos adicionales agregarlos con `append`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al tratar de enviar ambos objetos con `formdatax+formData`, Javascript intentará concatenarlos, quedando algo como `[Object Object][Object Object]`. Solo puedes enviar un objeto.

De preferencia usa `FormData` y, si no quieres complicarte modificando todo tu código actual, basta con:

```
let formData = new FormData();
// Recorrer el objeto actual
Object.keys(formdatax).forEach(key => {
    // Agregar cada elemento a formData
    formData.append(key, formdatax[key]);
});

// Finalmente agregas el archivo
let files = $('#foto_producto')[0].files[0];
formData.append('file',files);

// Ejecutas la petición AJAX enviando solo formData
$.post("procesos/registrar.php", formData).done(function(respp){
    alert(respp);
    //location.reload();
});
```

Con esto ya debería funcionar, aunque puedes simplificar y optimizar con la sugerencia de @A.Cedano en comentarios, enviando todo el formulario:

```
let formData = new FormData($('#id-de-formulario')[0]));
$.post("procesos/registrar.php", formData).done(function(respp){
    alert(respp);
    //location.reload();
});
```

Así se envían todos los campos del formulario, no importa si ya existían o los agregaste posteriormente; a menos que los hayas colocado fuera del formulario.

### Opción con Javascript puro

Por petición en comentarios, si estás usando jQuery solo por las peticiones AJAX y la forma de seleccionar campos, puedes ahorrarte unos cuantos KB de descarga en la página al omitir esa librería y hacerlo con Javascript puro:

Para crear el objeto JSON actual, remplazas `$` por `document.querySelector` y `.val()` por `.value`

```
formdatax = {
    tipo_reg: "producto",
    producto: document.querySelector("#producto").value,
    new_categoria: new_categoria,
    categoria: categoria,
    new_marca: new_marca,
    marca: marca,
    ubicacion: document.querySelector("#ubicacion").value,
    precio_costo : document.querySelector("#precio_costo").value,
    precio_minimo : document.querySelector("#precio_minimo").value,
    precio_mayor: document.querySelector("#precio_mayor").value,
    precio_venta: document.querySelector("#precio_venta").value,
    precio_consumidor: document.querySelector("#precio_consumidor").value,
    codigo_barras: document.querySelector("#codigo_barras").value,
    codigo_producto: document.querySelector("#codigo_producto").value,
    codigo_interno: document.querySelector("#codigo_interno").value
};
```

La forma de crear el objeto `FormData` no cambia, pero sí cómo agregas el archivo:

```
let formData = new FormData();
// Finalmente agregas el archivo
let files = document.querySelector('#foto_producto').files[0];
formData.append('file',files);
```

Si creas el objeto desde el formulario:

```
let formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('#id-de-formulario'));
```

La petición AJAX es la que tiene más cambios, pero la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) es muy sencilla:

```
// Ejecutas la petición AJAX enviando solo formData
fetch('procesos/registrar.php', {
    method: 'POST',    // Debes especificar el método
    body: formData     // Y agregar los datos que deseas enviar
}).then(resp => {
    // resp es la respuesta inicial del servidor
    // analizar si fue correcta:
    if(resp.ok) {
        // La respuesta fue correcta
        // Aquí puedes interpretar el resultado como JSON, texto, etc.
        // Supongamos que el servidor devuelve texto o HTML
        return resp.text();
    }
    // La respuesta no fue correcta, lanzar excepción
    throw resp.statusText;
}).then(data => {
    // Técnicamente, aquí finaliza la petición, después de interpretar la respuesta
    // y recibes el resultado de resp.text()
    console.log(data);
}).catch(error => {
    // Aquí recibirás todos los errores, incluida la excepción del primer .then()
    console.log('Error en petición AJAX: ' + error.message);
});
```

Comment: que pasa si son múltiples archivos que deseo enviar??? y otra cosa no veo como recibes en php los archivos enviados por ese metodo...

Comment: podrías explicar lo mismo sin jquery con javascript vanilla o emacs para que el OP Vea la diferencia?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso, si quieres enviar múltiples archivos, basta con crear el objeto `FormData` con el formulario como parámetro. Si se crea manualmente, se debe recorrer la propiedad `files` para agregar uno a uno. En PHP los vas a recibir como siempre en `$_FILES`.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso, servido, joven... opción sin jQuery agregada.

Comment: Excelente brother, eres un crack